# Conjunto de regras para identificação ortográfica

Tags: ortografia, acordo-ortográfico

Existe alguma forma sistemática de identificar qual acordo ortográfico um determinado texto em português foi escrito?

Qual o conjunto ótimo de palavras que podem ser utilizados para diferenciar em qual acordo ortográfico um texto foi escrito.

Há algum conjunto de palavras que permite identificar a ortografia de qual pais lusófono um determinado texto foi escrito?

Comment: Sim estou ciente do acordo e de que fiz "duas" perguntas, apesar de discordar, acho que está mais para uma pergunta com um possível desdobramento extatamente por conta do acordo ortográfico entre todos os países lusófonos. Apesar de existir ele não é implementado na sua forma mais estrita.

Comment: Lin, agora entendi. Em Portugal, realmente; mas no Brasil, até que é bem implementado, tirando *muçarela*. Uma pergunta, Lin: queres saber de 1911 em diante, já que em 1911 o português teve sua primeira ortografia oficial, ou desde o galego-português (séc. XIII), ou alguma outra coisa?

Comment: Acho que encontrar regra nem que seja para um subconjunto dos textos já seria parte do trabalho. Estou aqui perguntando realmente por que linguística não é a minha área, mas estou fazendo pesquisa nesta área e esta caracterização pode se tornar necessária. Talvez, se não houver, eu mesmo trabalhe no tema. Mas é sempre bom ouvir de outros especialistas antes de trabalhar em algo.

Comment: Lin, eu talvez escreva uma resposta, mas uma idéia boa seria ler uma gramática histórica, como Teyssier — Teyssier é o autor, eu não sei o nome do livro. Uma coisa que eu já posso te dizer de antemão é que há três períodos da ortografia portuguesa: uma fonética, escreve-se como se fala, cerca de até 1500, limite pouco preciso; uma etimológica, quando se tenta escrever etimologicamente, mas se errava muito, inclusive escrevendo uma palavra de dois modos no mesmo texto, mas em 1800 já está melhor, até 1911; de 1911 em diante, há ortografias oficiais.

Comment: Já li sobre isso. O que sei, é o que esta na wikipedia.

Comment: Eu diria que também depende muito do tipo de texto - textos formais tem mais probabilidade de seguirem mais à risca os acordos ortográficos, enquanto textos pessoais / informais dependem muito mais de quem escreve (i.e. de quando essas pessoas frequentaram a escola)

Answer (score 3):

Sabendo o conjunto básico de regras que foram alteradas em cada acordo e a data aproximada da implementação em cada país, você pode procurar por "marcadores" de cada reforma. Por exemplo:

- Se o texto tem palavras com MM para o som de M, MN para o som de N, PH para o som de F, CH para o som de K, TH para o som de T e entre outras, o texto foi escrito antes do Acordo de 1911 (ratificado por Portugal e Brasil na década de 30, e só implementado pelo Brasil na década de 40)
- Se o texto não tem as palavras grafadas como no item acima e tem palavras com acentos diferenciais - em particular os circunflexos - que não são usados nos dias de hoje (côr, êle...), ele foi escrito antes da Reforma Ortográfica de 1971 (Brasil, adotada em Portugal em 1973)
- Se o texto não tem as palavras grafadas como no item acima mas tem trema, alguns acentos diferenciais (pára, pêlo, pólo...), acentos agudos nos ditongos éi e ói de paroxítonas (idéia, platéia, alcalóide...) ou I e U tônicos precedidos de ditongo (feiúra...), entre outras alterações, ele foi escrito após 2009 (em Portugal) ou após 2016, quando entraram em vigor as regras do Acordo Ortográfico de 1990

Fontes:

http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/?action=acordo-historia

https://www.portugues.com.br/gramatica/guia-rapido-novo-acordo-ortografico.html

https://www.superprof.com.br/blog/numero-de-mudancas-na-lingua-portuguesa/

Comment: Ótima resposta, especialmente por considerar os acordos mais antigos. +1